# read most recent xlsx 2 files in a directory in R and merge it

Tags: r, magrittr

Is there any way to read most recent xlsx 2 files in a directory (in Windows System) in R and merge them to a single file?

The current code which I am using is pulling only the last file but I want last 2 files.

I have tried:

```
library(magrittr)
List <- list.files(path = "x", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  magrittr::extract(which.max(file.mtime(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can sort and `slice` the last 2

```
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files(path = "x", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.xlsx$")  %>%
    tibble(col1 = .) %>%
    arrange(file.mtime(col1)) %>%
    slice_tail(n = 2) %>%
    pull(col1)
```

If we need to join those files

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
out <- map_dfr(files, ~ read_excel(path = .x,  sheet = 1))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225802/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-read-most-recent-xlsx-2-files-in-a-directory-in-r).